# Details of mining

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

When i write `miner.start()` on my testnet geth node, it shows `Starting mining operation (CPU=4 TOT=6)`. What is the meaning of "CPU = 4 , TOT =6" and what does the changing value of these parameter signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the message, `CPU=4`, states that you are mining with 4 CPU threads.

When you execute the `miner.start()` command, `geth` will start mining with the maximum number of CPU threads you have installed on your computer.

You can also specify `miner.start({n})`, where `geth` will only start `{n}` threads, e.g., `miner.start(1)`.

The second part of the message, `TOT=6`, is the number of worker agents that `geth` starts.

Here is the code that emits the message from [go-ethereum/miner/miner.go, lines 102 to 124](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/miner/miner.go#L102-L124):

```
func (self *Miner) Start(coinbase common.Address, threads int) {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&self.shouldStart, 1)
    self.threads = threads
    self.worker.coinbase = coinbase
    self.coinbase = coinbase

    if atomic.LoadInt32(&self.canStart) == 0 {
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infoln("Can not start mining operation due to network sync (starts when finished)")
        return
    }

    atomic.StoreInt32(&self.mining, 1)

    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        self.worker.register(NewCpuAgent(i, self.pow))
    }

    glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("Starting mining operation (CPU=%d TOT=%d)\n", threads, len(self.worker.agents))

    self.worker.start()

    self.worker.commitNewWork()
}
```